# Prevent users from accessing a folder in a mapped drive

Tags: wired-networking, mapped-drive

I run outlook backups to the server within my company, I have a mapped a drive to all computers within the company and a folder within it as where the backups go to automatically with the help of safepst.

Now the problem is since they can all see this drive and folder anyone can pick anyone's backup or delete it.

Is there a way to either prevent users from seeing the mapped drive or folder or set permissions so they can't see or delete while safepst will still be able to access and update the backup?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several ways to control access:

1. Via shares (you can control who has which rights).
2. Via the filesystem (same idea but on fs level).

Whatever you do, pick on of the two and do not mix. It will save you a lot of headaches. And if you have a domain then grant rights based on access groups.

With each pst in its own folder (preferably even a own homedir) and permissions restricted on that folder only the allowed people can open that folder. Or delete, or write, ...

For a more detailed answer who would need more information. E.g. is that share on a fileserver? Are you asing active directory? If not how did you grant access ('full access' to 'everyone', something more detailed? ...)

Comment: Its on the c of my server and i shared the folder granting access to everyone.

Comment: Its on the c of my server and i shared the folder granting access to everyone. I dont use an active directory setup and log them on through my administrator account on the server then map the folder to them.  i hope im clearer now. so how do i get to use any of the options uve just given to ensure safepst can write to the folder but users cannot delete or move the folder apart from i the administrator

Comment: Using the same way you already shared on folder with 'everyone' you can also create separate shares and limit these to one user. That way only that user can access that folder, effectively creating a homedir for her/him.

Comment: Not aksed but: why share on C:. That is usually where the OS is and unless you set quota this means that users can fill the disk. You server will not like that. Typically a server is partitioned into a volume with the OS and one with user data. (e.g. C: for OS and programs,  D:\ for data).

Comment: Thanx will look at partitioning it soon. but atm is there a way to make the folder only writtable put people cant delete? i also dont have an active dir system hence cant crete the other userts

Comment: You can create LOCAL users on the fileserver. IT is not as convenient as doing that once in a central place (via AD), but you can create an account per user and share that with your users. As to only writeable and no delete: Not sure.  Look at the security tab and play with "create files/write data" allowed and "delete files" and "delete subfolders and files" both on denied.

Comment: NTFS permissions on the hard disk override share permissions. So you can grant all users access to the share, but then go to the folder in question on the machine and change the Security settings and Deny access to the appropriate groups (or simply uncheck Read and write access)